# I have to insert random black color in a grid of 5x3 and each row should only contain one black cell

Tags: android

I have to insert random black color in a grid of 5x3 and each row should only contain one black cell and the left  over 2 cells in a row should of white color and each row should have a random black. I have to do this in android using Canvas.
 need to use a random function to generate one random black in a cell in each row.
How can I do this?

```
public class MyView extends View {


int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0, counter3 = 0, counter4 = 0, counter5 = 0;
float cellWidth, cellHeight, height, width;

Paint paint = new Paint();


public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10);


    pBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pWhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);

}

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(0, counter1, cellWidth, cellHeight + counter1, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter1, cellWidth * 2, cellHeight + counter1, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter1, cellWidth * 3, cellHeight + counter1, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter2 + cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight * 2 + counter2, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter2 + cellHeight, cellWidth * 2, cellHeight * 2 + counter2, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter2 + cellHeight, cellWidth * 3, cellHeight * 2 + counter2, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter3 + cellHeight * 2, cellWidth, cellHeight * 3 + counter3, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter3 + cellHeight * 2, cellWidth * 2, cellHeight * 3 + counter3, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter3 + cellHeight * 2, cellWidth * 3, cellHeight * 3 + counter3, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter4 + cellHeight * 3, cellWidth, cellHeight * 4 + counter4, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter4 + cellHeight * 3, cellWidth * 2, cellHeight * 4 + counter4, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, counter4 + cellHeight * 3, cellWidth * 3, cellHeight * 4 + counter4, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, -cellHeight + counter5, cellWidth, 0 + counter5, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, -cellHeight + counter5, cellWidth * 2, 0 + counter5, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, -cellHeight + counter5, cellWidth * 3, 0 + counter5, paint);


}

private Runnable animate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (counter1 < cellHeight) {
            counter1 += 5;
        } else {
            counter1 = 0;
        }
        if (counter2 < cellHeight) {
            counter2 += 5;
        } else {
            counter2 = 0;
        }
        if (counter3 < cellHeight) {
            counter3 += 5;
        } else {
            counter3 = 0;
        }
        if (counter4 < cellHeight) {
            counter4 += 5;
        } else {
            counter4 = 0;
        }
        if (counter5 < cellHeight) {
            counter5 += 5;
        } else {
            counter5 = 0;
        }
        invalidate();
        postDelayed(this, 10);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = parentHeight;
    width = parentWidth;
    cellHeight = parentHeight / 4;
    cellWidth = parentWidth / 3;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following random method :

```
private int getRandomNumber(int min, int max){ //range from 1 to 3

return Random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the full code as I am a beginner in android